# WPF databinding not working

Tags: wpf, data-binding

```
private MyObject _myObject;
public MyObject MyObject
{
    get { return _myObject; }
    set
    {
        if (_myObject != value)
        {
            _myObject = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => MyObject);
        }
    }
}


<TextBox Text="{Binding MyObject.MyObjectProperty}"/>
```

When starting my app, MyObject is initialized, the MyObjectProperty is shown in my TextBox, but when I change the MyObjectProperty of MyObject, the TextBox is not updated!

Comment: Does your MyObject also raise property changed notifications?

Comment: Do you mean if MyObject also implements INotifyPropertyChanged? If yes the answer is no, MyObject is a Model object, only my ViewModels implement the INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: To make your code work, you need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged on MyObject as well - refer to @blindmeis answer

Comment: If your posted code is accurate then you've missed something: your binding doesn't match your property name (`MyObjectProperty` vs `MyObject`).  Which is it and what else have you missed?

Comment: try the '_myObject = value;' before the if-operator in your property. sometimes it's working, then there is something wrong :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does your MyObject object implement INotifyPropertyChanged and call it?

```
public class MyObject
{
private string _prop;
public string MyObjectProperty
{
  get { return _prop; }
  set
  {
    if (_prop!= value)
    {
        _prop = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => MyObjectProperty);
    }
 }
}
}
```

and the default UpdateSourceTrigger is LostFocus so you have to leave the textbox to see anything

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what blindmeis said, make sure you also specify two way binding on the textbox.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=MyObject.MyProperty, Mode=TwoWay"}/>
```

Comment: You don't need it, Controls like TextBox have default TwoWay mode.

Comment: @Stacked - Good point and that is true for WPF.  Silverlight, on the other hand, does not default it.  I always forget which settings apply to which technology.  :)